# How to normalize histogram well?

Tags: probability, statistics, probability-theory, normal-distribution

**UPDATE 2**

The question may be formulated as follows:

Is there any common probability distribution, like normal distribution, but which has sharp (or just sharper) edges? If yes, then I could approximate data with this distribution.

**ORIGINAL**

Suppose I have some histogram like following

[image]

and I want to normalize it, i.e. rescale values (in vertical dimension), say, to range [0..255].

The problem is that it is not well if I take just minimum and maximum values, since they probably contain outbreaks (like bin near 100 on picture).

Is there a way to calculate minimum and maximum in statistical way, something like 3 sigma or something?

I know I can just drop few maximal and minimal values as it done in sports.

**UPDATE**

This histogram is result of image evaluation in unknown (random) space, depending on color and other properties of image scanned. I want to scale it into [0..1] range to compare between each other.

Regard this as `1D` grayscale image and I want to make it of uniform brightness and contrast.

Comment: In a conventional [histogam](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Histogram), area matters and $0$ is meaningful, so you may need to explain why you want to change the minimum

Answer (score 0):

You have hit on many of the issues.  What you should do is not a mathematical question, and everything you have suggested is possible.  A simple scaling by $\frac {255}{155}$ is a reasonable idea.  For many purposes, the spike near $100$ wouldn't worry me-it isn't so far out of family that you lose information about the other bins.  If it were three or four times higher than any other bin I would worry more.  Dropping off the bottom, say taking $10$ counts input to $0$ output is possible, but if ratios between the bins are important you shouldn't do that.  You can certainly calculate the mean and standard deviation-those are well defined formulas.  Should you exclude points over $3 \sigma$ from the mean?  If the distribution were normal (and most are not-they have longer tails) you would expect one real point in $370$ to be that far away and you have $255$.  I would set the threshold higher for exclusion, if I did it at all.